# I see myself consistently falling into micro-sleep at work

Tags: motivation

As a web developer, I see myself consistently falling into micro-sleep - mainly at the beggining of afternoons and during the end of mornings. Obviously, my productivity isn't the best.

I pay attention about what I eat, how much I sleep and the sport I do ; and I have tried over the years to get some technics to trouble-shoot that problem, but nothing seems to work out.

Any idea, any tips on how to solve this kind of issue ?

PS: I am not too sure if this question is suitable for *the workplace* - so if there is a site on stackexchange network that is more suitable than here, please let me know :)

Comment: I don't know about your medical condition, and it's a private thing, so I will just give 2 links here (NAA... ?) but it can be helpful. People suffering of [sleep apnea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_apnea) encounter [excessive daytime sleepiness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excessive_daytime_sleepiness). Could it be (part) of your problem?

Comment: Have been to the doctor already?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsleep plenty of things that you might have that can cause microsleep, frrom sleep apnea to  schizophrenia. So if you have not seen a doctor yet, just do so.

Comment: Are you bored or demotivated? That might also factor in to it.

Comment: To echo @OldPadawan, check your score on the [Epworth Sleepiness Scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epworth_Sleepiness_Scale) and strongly consider seeking medical attention.You can't 'technique' yourself out of a medical problem

Comment: Looks like a question that would be more suited for https://health.stackexchange.com/ ...

Comment: Have you considered getting a [standing desk riser?](https://www.amazon.com/Lorell-Sit-to-Stand-monitor-riser-black/dp/B017NMXBPS) these are very useful for me to remain productive and alert throughout the day. My company, and many other companies that I have heard of are more than willing to provide these for their employees because of the productivity (as well as health) benefits that they provide.

Comment: It **would** have been fine on Productivity.SE :-(

Comment: @RoryAlsop , I wouldn't have thought there were a SE about Productivity !! Thanks for the info.... and I see, why you put it in bold letters : there are no productivity se, it didn't go through the beta.

Comment: Unfortunately just not enough interest. Few questions asked. Very few experienced productivity specialists.

Comment: Diagnosing your self on the internet is the worse you can do. Just see the responses here and should be clear. Btw, its' very normal to be sleepy at certain times in a day. That's why people invented "siesta"! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siesta

Comment: Get to the doctor.  Specifically ask about Thyroid tests and sleep apnea.

Answer (score 7):

Medical issues aside, I'm not a doctor, nor is there enough information to draw a meaningful conclusion.

I face the same issues as you describe. I often am pretty productive until around lunch. After lunch I get another hour or so of productiveness, but then the sleepiness kicks in. Near the end of the day I get more productive again. I have done the following to counteract this:

- I used to drink a lot of coffee, think liters not cups, I try to keep the coffee to a maximum of 4 cups before lunch, otherwise I crash after lunch and I'm not worth anything anymore for the rest of the day unless I keep tanking coffee.
- I lunch late, I noticed I can keep going before lunch much easier than after. So I take my break later than most, giving me at least a morning and a half of good productivity. Eat breakfast at the office before starting work if you can't wait so long.
- I drink at least two glasses of water with my lunch. It helps break down the caffeine that's been building up since the start of the day. I don't drink any coffee for at least two hours or so after lunch. This mitigates the caffeine crash effect during the afternoon.
- I go to bed early and get up early. It's easier to last the whole day at the office if I've been awake for an hour or two before work already.
- I try to binge code during the morning, finishing as much programming work during my most productive time. I use a headset if noise breaks my concentration, I need this time. During the afternoon I shift my activities to doing code reviews, doing research for upcoming issues, etc.
- If I still get sleepy I drink some more coffee, but at least two hours after lunch and 2-3 cups at most during the afternoon. (yes I have a problem with caffeine). I also drink a glass of water with every cup of coffee in the afternoon.
- If I really can't stay concentrated and drift off, I put on some fast or loud music, try your favourite game's music if you don't know what to listen to, game music is designed to hype you up while not being a distraction.

And like the others have said, go visit a doctor.

Comment: Sounds like solid advice I've done similar but I reduced coffee to 1 a day maybe 3pm and drink black tea instead.

Comment: Seconded see the doctor I used to hit a wall about 3 if I ate to much of the wrong sort of food - though this was the side effect of a chronic kidney illness

Comment: I discovered mate-tea to have a much gentler *caffeine crash effect*. Worth a try if you can stand the taste.

Comment: It also makes me a little bit uneasy that the most top voted answer basically advocates *drugging* yourself to keep productive - even if I have to admit most of us, including me, to this to some degree ...

Comment: @Daniel I would argue I'm more advocating the "responsible use" of drugs rather than the drugs themselves. I wouldn't advise anyone to start drinking coffee if they didn't already, just to keep productive. But if OP does drink a lot of coffee, like me and many other programmers, it could very well be a cause of their problem. Moderation is key.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to consider here is your sleep quality. Is it good? do you get enough of it? (you mention paying attention, but not a number of hours) if not, start by improving this.

Then, you have to admit that your performance varies with the time of day. I, like you, find myself more easily distracted or even drowsy around noon, which is why i use that time to perform more physical tasks (even replacing a coffee break with a 10-minutes walk), or more engaging ones, where my motivation compensates for my "tiredness".

The last thing you have to consider is, as @Erik said, your motivation. Do you love your job? If not, your lack of energy is but a symptom of your lack of motivation.

Now if you sleep for 8 straight hours each night, eat healthy meals (inc. breakfast...), love your job and still fall asleep, it is time to go see a doctor.

Answer (score 3):

This is a medical issue that I also struggle with.  When was the last time you had labs done?  For me I am borderline diabetic and am struggling to keep my blood sugar down and lose weight.  It is a bit of a vicious cycle as I could lose weight more easily if my blood sugar was lower, but I need to lose weight to lower my blood sugar.

It can also be overnight sleep related, but that can also steam from blood sugar issues.  The most important take away from all of this is to see a doctor and possibly a dietitian.

It may be a sleep apnea thing, or it could be a blood sugar thing.  I don't take them every night but Belsomra is a great non addictive sleeping pill.

In the short term, getting up and taking a walk or incorporating a standing desk is a great idea.

Comment: Standing desk+taking walks throught the day are great ideas. I wouldn't recommend any kind of medicine on such website - some people might take this advice lightly and take medicine without seeing a doctor. However, to recommend seeing a doctor (and let him prescribe medicine if needed) would be a better approach. Thanks for your input about standing desk+taking walks

Comment: Beside, about your vicious circle : I am sure you can takle it :) You will have to change some habits to do so (IMO eating less each meal and healthier, while eating more fruits, will be a great start). Best of luck (and sorry for the unsollicited advice..)

Comment: @Cedric, I am doing all of that and running triathlons (I ran my first at age 50), still it is tough.

Comment: Running thriathlons not only make you fitter (sport is ALWAYS good), but probably makes you meet some like-minded people whose focus are partially the same as yours. Keep it up!

Answer (score 1):

If this is occurring at the beginning of the afternoon, is there any chance you could take the last 10-15 minutes of a lunch or any other break and take a nap?

In some workplaces (traditional), if you do this at your desk people with think you're slacking off. Have a conversation with your boss about it and make sure she knows you're trying to do something about it. Hopefully, she'll recognize that you're better off than trying to fight through it. Your work will suffer.

Some people struggle to fall asleep. I don't, but when I'm tired, it is very difficult to stay awake. Being able to nod off for a few minutes really helps and is sometimes unavoidable.

Answer (score 1):

*Apart from making sure to have a thourough checkup from a doctor to see if there are any medical reasons that need treatment,* I suggest you learn [autogenic training](https://bebrainfit.com/autogenic-training/).

Whenever you feel the tiredness creeping up, you log out of your time tracking, if any, seek a quiet place and take your 5-10 minutes to regenerate - just as your colleagues having a smoke, only much healthier.

I know this can be a little hard ´do in some places, but try to find a way. This is for the benefit of your employer also, so if you tell him that you found a way to maximize your productivity and they do not have to pay for the time, they should be supportive.